# Detect iOS device is Moving right or left or up or down

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Hi some body now how can I make this how detect if the device is moving right or left referenced to some point. 
Like Night Sky app I know  to determinate the attitude of the device is with `coreMotion` but I don't find how can I detect that. i can detect roll pitch and yaw but this how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]` and set its delegate. Using the method

```
 - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

You can get the movements of the device. Look also at the references of [UIAccelerometre](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAccelerometer/sharedAccelerometer) and [UIAcceleration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006901). You can track the movement using the `x`, `y` and `z` properties of the `UIAcceleration`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the accelerometer. Every iOS device has one. A trip to Google should get you an answer. If you were looking for code, sorry. I don't memorize that kind of stuff.

Comment: Accelerometer for this does not work because i need to move the ipad to right to left up and down not in only one point like 40cm to right etc.

Comment: You can still use the accelerometer for this. Google `Core Motion`.

Comment: Thanks Erway I looking for very much in Google but I dont finde how can i make this kind of stuff can you give some link or some info of that if you have thanks Erway.

Comment: To clarify: you want to determine the attitude of the device?